# Campo calculado que muestre fecha termino de un contrato

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, oracle

necesito ayuda con crear un campo o columna que indique la fecha de termino de un contrato, según me dieron a entender para lograr esto se tiene que considerar la fecha de creación o renovación mas los meses de plazo o plazo de renovación. Ahora adjuntare parte del código para que se entienda mejor en lo que necesito ayuda.

También quiero agregar que estoy trabajando con SQL developer de Oracle, lo que quiero lograr es que en la pagina de la foto aparezca un campo fecha que indique la fecha en que se acabara el contrato que se coloque en los otros campos

```html
CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW "SAI"."SAI_CC_CONTRATOS_V" ("NRO_CONTRATO", "RUT_CLIENTE", "NOM_CLIENTE", "FECHA_CREACION", "FECHA_RENOVACION", "MONEDA", "FECHA_TIPO_CAMBIO", "PLAZO", "PLAZO_RENOVACION", "CARGO_FIJO", "MIN_BN_CONTRATO", "MIN_COLOR_CONTRATO", "PERIODICIDAD_MIN", "RENOV_AUTO", "REAJUSTE", "TIPO_CONTRATO", "VACACIONES_ENERO", "VACACIONES_FEBRERO", "VACACIONES_JULIO", "COD_RUBRO", "RUBRO", "ESTADO_CONTRATO", "AREA_NEGOCIO", "DIR_FACTURACION", "COMUNA", "CIUDAD", "REGION", "HH", "SERIE", "MODELO", "ESTADO_HH", "MIN_GARANTIZADO_BN_HH", "MIN_GARANTIZADO_COLOR_HH", "TARIFA_BN", "TARIFA_COLOR", "CF_EQUIPO", "SLA", "CONDICIONES_DE_PAGO", "EJECUTIVO_COMERCIAL", "EJECUTIVO_POST_VENTA") AS 
  SELECT sc.id AS nro_contrato,
            SCL.CUSTOMER_NUMERIC,
            SCL.CUSTOMER_NAME,
            TRUNC (SC.FECHA_CREACION),
            TRUNC (SC.FECHA_RENOVACION),
            sc.tipo_moneda,
            nvl(FTC.NOMBRe,' '),
            SP.DESCRIPCION,
            SPL.DESCRIPCION,
            SC.CARGO_FIJO_GLOBAL,
            SC.MG_BN,
            SC.MG_COLOR,
            SC.PERIODICIDAD_MINIMOS,
            DECODE (SC.RENOVACION_AUTOMATICA,  1, 'SI',  0, 'NO'),
            DECODE (SC.REAJUSTE,  1, 'SI',  0, 'NO'),
            ST.DESCRIPCION,
            DECODE (sc.vacaciones_enero, 1, 'SI', ' '),
            DECODE (sc.vacaciones_febrero, 1, 'SI', ' '),
            DECODE (sc.vacaciones_julio, 1, 'SI', ' '),
            st.id_rubro_erp,
            sru.valor,
            sc.estado,
            san.meaning AS area_negocio,
            dfa.address1,
            dfa.city,
            dfa.county,
            dfa.state,
            slc.nro_hh,
            slc.nro_serie,
            SGD.NOMBRE,
            SLC.ESTADO_LIN,
            slc.mg_bn,
            slc.mg_color,
            slc.tarifa_bn,
            slc.tarifa_color,
            slc.cargo_fijo,
            sla.description,
            cp.DESCRIPTION CONDICIONES_DE_PAGO
            , sv.NOMBRE EJECUTIVO_COMERCIAL
            , eje.NOMBRE EJECUTIVO_POST_VENTA
       FROM saiapp_contrato sc,
            SAIAPP_CONTRATOLINEA slc,
            saiapp_clientev scl,
            saiapp_gcc_mfp sgc,
            saiapp_gcc_modelo sgd,
            SAIAPP_PLAZOCONTRATO sp,
            SAIAPP_PLAZOCONTRATO spl,
            SAIAPP_TIPOTRANSACCION st,
            SAIAPP_DIRECCIONFACTURACIONV dfa,
            SAIAPP_SLA sla,
            SAIAPP_VENDEDOR sv,
            SAIAPP_AREANEGOCIO san,
            SAIAPP_SUBRUBRO sru,  
            SAIAPP_FECHATIPOCAMBIO    ftc,
            SAIAPP_CONDICIONESDEPAGO cp
            , SAIAPP_VENDEDOR eje
      WHERE             --               sc.id = 58513
                --  AND
                sc.id > 0 -- 52321                            --  in ( 44257 , 52156  )
            AND slc.contrato_id(+) = sc.id
            AND slc.nro_hh = SGc.HH(+)
            AND SGc.MODELO_ID = SGd.ID(+)
            AND sc.cliente_id = scl.customer_id
            AND SC.ESTADO IN ('VALIDADO', 'RETENIDO', 'PENDIENTE', 'CANCELADO')
            AND sc.PLAZO_CONTRATO_ID = sp.id(+)
            AND sc.PLAZO_RENOVACION_ID = spl.id(+)
            AND sc.TIPO_TRANSACCION_ID = st.id(+)
            AND dfa.id(+) = sc.direccionfacturacion_id
            AND sla.id(+) = slc.sla_id
            AND sv.id(+) = sc.vendedor_id
            AND san.id(+) = SV.AREA_NEGOCIO_ID
            AND sru.id_erp(+) = sc.subrubro
            AND sc.CONDICIONES_DE_PAGO_ID = cp.ID
            AND SLC.ESTADO_LIN IN ('VALIDADA', 'INSTALADA')
            --or sc.fecha_tipo_cambio_id is null
            --and  ftc.id = sc.fecha_tipo_cambio_id 
            AND eje.ID(+) = sc.EJECUTIVO_COMERCIAL_ID
   ORDER BY 1;
```

[image: Agregar campo que diga fecha termino de contrato]

Comment: Buenas, Álvaro, bienvenido al sitio. Sería interesante que indicaras cuales son los campos relevantes para tu duda y cual es exactamente la relación entre ellos. Todos los campos que aparecen en esa consulta no sirven prácticamente para nada en relación a tu problema . ¿Cómo se calcula la fecha de término exactamente?

Comment: @RubioRic gracias por responder estimado, los campos que se tendrían que calcular serian fecha creación, fecha renovación, plazo y plazo renovación

Comment: ¿cuál es la columna y la tabla que tiene el valor del plazo? el valor es de meses?

Answer (score 0):

puedes usar un campo date. Pero yo suelo usar un campo numerico(8) donde guardo la fecha en formato AAAAMMDD para facilitar las comparaciones y los ordenamientos.

```html
CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW "SAI"."SAI_CC_CONTRATOS_V" ("NRO_CONTRATO", "RUT_CLIENTE", "NOM_CLIENTE", "FECHA_CREACION", "FECHA_RENOVACION", "MONEDA", "FECHA_TIPO_CAMBIO", "PLAZO", "PLAZO_RENOVACION", "CARGO_FIJO", "MIN_BN_CONTRATO", "MIN_COLOR_CONTRATO", "PERIODICIDAD_MIN", "RENOV_AUTO", "REAJUSTE", "TIPO_CONTRATO", "VACACIONES_ENERO", "VACACIONES_FEBRERO", "VACACIONES_JULIO", "COD_RUBRO", "RUBRO", "ESTADO_CONTRATO", "AREA_NEGOCIO", "DIR_FACTURACION", "COMUNA", "CIUDAD", "REGION", "HH", "SERIE", "MODELO", "ESTADO_HH", "MIN_GARANTIZADO_BN_HH", "MIN_GARANTIZADO_COLOR_HH", "TARIFA_BN", "TARIFA_COLOR", "CF_EQUIPO", "SLA", "CONDICIONES_DE_PAGO", "EJECUTIVO_COMERCIAL", "EJECUTIVO_POST_VENTA") AS 
  SELECT sc.id AS nro_contrato,
            SCL.CUSTOMER_NUMERIC,
            SCL.CUSTOMER_NAME,
            TRUNC (SC.FECHA_CREACION),
            TRUNC (SC.FECHA_RENOVACION),
            sc.tipo_moneda,
            nvl(FTC.NOMBRe,' '),
            SP.DESCRIPCION,
            SPL.DESCRIPCION,
            SC.CARGO_FIJO_GLOBAL,
            SC.MG_BN,
            SC.MG_COLOR,
            SC.PERIODICIDAD_MINIMOS,
            DECODE (SC.RENOVACION_AUTOMATICA,  1, 'SI',  0, 'NO'),
            DECODE (SC.REAJUSTE,  1, 'SI',  0, 'NO'),
            ST.DESCRIPCION,
            DECODE (sc.vacaciones_enero, 1, 'SI', ' '),
            DECODE (sc.vacaciones_febrero, 1, 'SI', ' '),
            DECODE (sc.vacaciones_julio, 1, 'SI', ' '),
            st.id_rubro_erp,
            sru.valor,
            sc.estado,
            san.meaning AS area_negocio,
            dfa.address1,
            dfa.city,
            dfa.county,
            dfa.state,
            slc.nro_hh,
            slc.nro_serie,
            SGD.NOMBRE,
            SLC.ESTADO_LIN,
            slc.mg_bn,
            slc.mg_color,
            slc.tarifa_bn,
            slc.tarifa_color,
            slc.cargo_fijo,
            sla.description,
            cp.DESCRIPTION CONDICIONES_DE_PAGO
            , sv.NOMBRE EJECUTIVO_COMERCIAL
            , eje.NOMBRE EJECUTIVO_POST_VENTA
       FROM saiapp_contrato sc,
            SAIAPP_CONTRATOLINEA slc,
            saiapp_clientev scl,
            saiapp_gcc_mfp sgc,
            saiapp_gcc_modelo sgd,
            SAIAPP_PLAZOCONTRATO sp,
            SAIAPP_PLAZOCONTRATO spl,
            SAIAPP_TIPOTRANSACCION st,
            SAIAPP_DIRECCIONFACTURACIONV dfa,
            SAIAPP_SLA sla,
            SAIAPP_VENDEDOR sv,
            SAIAPP_AREANEGOCIO san,
            SAIAPP_SUBRUBRO sru,  
            SAIAPP_FECHATIPOCAMBIO    ftc,
            SAIAPP_CONDICIONESDEPAGO cp
            , SAIAPP_VENDEDOR eje
      WHERE             --               sc.id = 58513
                --  AND
                sc.id > 0 -- 52321                            --  in ( 44257 , 52156  )
            AND slc.contrato_id(+) = sc.id
            AND slc.nro_hh = SGc.HH(+)
            AND SGc.MODELO_ID = SGd.ID(+)
            AND sc.cliente_id = scl.customer_id
            AND SC.ESTADO IN ('VALIDADO', 'RETENIDO', 'PENDIENTE', 'CANCELADO')
            AND sc.PLAZO_CONTRATO_ID = sp.id(+)
            AND sc.PLAZO_RENOVACION_ID = spl.id(+)
            AND sc.TIPO_TRANSACCION_ID = st.id(+)
            AND dfa.id(+) = sc.direccionfacturacion_id
            AND sla.id(+) = slc.sla_id
            AND sv.id(+) = sc.vendedor_id
            AND san.id(+) = SV.AREA_NEGOCIO_ID
            AND sru.id_erp(+) = sc.subrubro
            AND sc.CONDICIONES_DE_PAGO_ID = cp.ID
            AND SLC.ESTADO_LIN IN ('VALIDADA', 'INSTALADA')
            --or sc.fecha_tipo_cambio_id is null
            --and  ftc.id = sc.fecha_tipo_cambio_id 
            AND eje.ID(+) = sc.EJECUTIVO_COMERCIAL_ID
   ORDER BY 1;
```

Comment: gracias por responder estimada pero como se logra hacer que se sumen los campos que mencione al campo fecha termino? aun no logro hacer eso

Comment: Para comparar u ordenar fechas no se necesita usar columnas o campos de tipo numérico eso se logra directamente con el tipo DATE